# Can we use managed lightning component in lightning application

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning

I created a lightning component and included in a managed package.
I installed that managed package in some org and there I want to use that component in lightning application, the managed lightning component is available but I am not able to use that component in any new Lightning application.
I tried the following trick to include managed component in lightning application, suppose package namespace is "xyz" then I tried to include like

```
xyx:myComponent and c:xyz__myComponent
```

Here is the component structure:-

```
aura:component controller="KendoController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId"
```

Can someone tell what I am missing to include managed component?

Comment: A question out of context: Were you able to setup kendo fw in lightning?

Comment: Yes Ashwini and I also found the solution, used access attribute of component that resolved my issue

Answer (score 4):

You can use managed lightning component in other lightning app.

There is an attribute named `access` which needs to be set. For ex:

```
<aura:component access="global" controller="KendoController" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId">
```

Comment: Is the opposite one available, too? I want to use organization lightning component inside of managed package.

Comment: Yes! no special keyword is needed for this @efirat